# is there a way to get the memory's that user have in his google photos from the api?

Tags: google-photos

i  am currently working on a project where I need to access the 'Memories' feature of Google Photos through their API. For those unfamiliar, 'Memories' in Google Photos is a feature that resurfaces old photos and videos for the user.

I have gone through the official Google Photos API documentation but couldn't find a direct reference or method to access these 'Memories'. My primary goal is to retrieve these specific memory collections programmatically.